# Show Location Details

Tags: opengts

In which class is generated "Show Location Details" report at Vehicle Map ? 
I think is in "ReportDisplay.java" but i am not finding it , please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it ... Is at TrackMap.java at write method this section :

```
out.write("<div id='"+MapProvider.ID_DETAIL_TABLE+"' style='width:100%;'></div>\n");
```

And the modification of html generated "showLocationDetail" can be modified at :
jsmap.js at

> jsmShowDetailReport()